# MahApps PasswordBox not showing the clear button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm using the latest MahApps WPF toolkit and I'm having a bit of trouble with applying my own styles onto its controls, precisely the PasswordBox.
I've defined the styles in a separate .xaml file which is included in the App.xaml file so that it is globally visible, across all .xaml files.
But when I use the style specified under a key the MahApps ClearTextButton refuses to appear on the control.

Here is my style:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultPasswordBoxStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type PasswordBox}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment">
        <Setter.Value>Center</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>16</Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And its usage in a separate .xaml file:

```
<PasswordBox Margin="{StaticResource ControlMargin}"
             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
             Style="{StaticResource DefaultPasswordBoxStyle}"
             Width="200" />
```

If I delete the Style attribute the button shows as it is supposed but want to be able to apply my own styles also. It is actually visible in the XAML designer, which is funny. I tried DynamicResource, as well, but with the same results.

Comment: I don't have time to confirm so just as comment, but your `BasedOn` value is pointed at a TargetType, not a Key, I think what you're actually looking for is `BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroPasswordBox}"` at least from looking at the [default template](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.PasswordBox.xaml) that includes the PART_ClearText button.

Comment: It says that it cannot find resource MetroPasswordBox. Do I need to include something other than the Metro.Controls namespace?

Comment: Is your style living in its own Resource Dictionary? If so, do you have the MahApps resource dictionary declared as a [MergedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in it so that it even knows a path to reach the style you're basing yours from as reference?

Comment: The path to MahApps files is in App.xaml and my own styles are in a separate Resource Dictionary. I'll try merging it somehow and report back. This is how it looks like so far - https://app.box.com/s/5iub1259ndnrrz7v3215t617ny1uvbre I've included the App.xaml and MainSkin.xaml files. Its all there.

Comment: Yea you just have to provide the path for everything to find each other, but be careful to do it right or you can cause yourself some real performance headaches. I'm leaving for the day, cheers!

Comment: Cannot get it to work, oh well.

Comment: Scratch that, it actually works but VS isn't able to find it (it gets underlined, doesn't matter). Write an answer when you get back. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to continue on from the original comments, you had a `Type` set as your Resource instead of pointing to a Key name. So once you gave your new custom template a proper path to find the original Style template as a `BasedOn` condition to inherit the rest of the MahApps style then the issue was resolved.

The VS underlining/not locating the resource thing, well I run into that all the time and I'm kind of convinced it's a defect in VS though I wouldn't mind knowing how to clear that off as well. It's annoying since sometimes it will have those errors in the IDE, sometimes it won't, lots of fun.

In the meantime, now that you have your template referencing the correct one as its base with the resource dictionaries referenced properly then all is well in the world again. Hope this helped, cheers!